# SFML and STL: What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, stl, sfml

I have the following code snippets:

```
void RemoveButton::triggerAction(team &team, unsigned int index)
{
    switch (mAction)
    {
        case Action::remove:

        {
            //team.mTeamMembers.erase(std::remove(team.mTeamMembers.begin(), team.mTeamMembers.end(), team.mTeamMembers.at(index)), team.mTeamMembers.end());
            team.mTeamMembers.erase(team.mTeamMembers.begin() + index);

            for (unsigned int i = index; i < team.mTeamMembers.size(); i++)
            {
                team.mTeamMembers[i].mRemoveButton->getText().move(0.0f, -30.0f);
                team.mTeamMembers[i].mText.move(0.0f, -30.0f);
            }

            team.mAddPosition.y -= 30.0f;
            break;
        }

        default:break;
    }
}

class team
{
public:
    size_t                                        teamNumber;
    std::vector<AddButton>                        mAddButtons;
    std::vector<teamRecord>                        mTeamMembers;

    sf::Sprite                                    mBorder;
    sf::Text                                    mText;
    Selector<AddButton>                            mAddButtons_Selector;
    sf::Vector2f                                mAddPosition;
    Selector<teamRecord>                        mTeamMembers_Selector;

    team(sf::Vector2f borderPosition, sf::Vector2f removeButtonsPosition, sf::Vector2f textPosition, size_t teamNumb, std::string text);
};
```

How *should* I erase an element from the team.mTeamMembers STL vector? The way I do it currently results in *seemingly* random execution errors, specifically when clicking the non-existent sprite of a deleted button. The commented line that uses std::remove is not compiled, and I do not understand why. As I'm feeling confused a.f. , can someone please shine some light here? Here's the build log while using std::remove, as recommended by some users on this forum:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Complex OOP Menus, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  RemoveButton.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\algorithm(1454): error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'teamRecord' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(389): note: could be 'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(381): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(373): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\system_error(365): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception(339): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) throw()'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception(334): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception(329): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\algorithm(1454): note: while trying to match the argument list '(teamRecord, const teamRecord)'
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\algorithm(1467): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::_Remove_unchecked<teamRecord*,_Ty>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _FwdIt=teamRecord *,
1>              _Ty=teamRecord
1>          ]
1>  ..\Data\Source\RemoveButton.cpp(24): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt std::remove<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<teamRecord>>>,teamRecord>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _FwdIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<teamRecord>>>,
1>              _Ty=teamRecord
1>          ]
```

If there is not enough information here, I could post the github link to my project, but it's pretty big and it would take time to sift through the code.

Comment: Please improve your question's title, so that it describes the question and helps others in the future.

Comment: _"I have the following code snippets: If there is not enough information here, I could post the github link to my project, but it's pretty big and it would take time to sift through the code."_ The Help Centre instructs you to compose and present a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::remove()` doesn't make any sense to me if you already know the position/offset and you only want to remove a single entry.

You're receiving your error with `std::remove()` most likely due to the fact that there's no equality operator (`operator ==`) defined for your `teamRecord` class (or it just isn't found).

> The way I do it currently results in *seemingly* random execution errors, specifically when clicking the non-existent sprite of a deleted button.

That's something we can't look at unless we see the code regarding that. How can you click something not existing? Any chance you're just missing a check or not cleaning up things properly?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by double checking the index *I was giving* to the elements on insertion. Thanks and sorry for such a stupid mistake!